# Trying to get PHP form to query SQL database using multiple if statements

Tags: php, html, sql, forms

First timer here. I am trying to use a PHP/HTML form to query by database and then print an output of the results that were found. Problem is, I keep getting a syntax error on the last line of code(ish) it changes from being the line after `</html>` to the `</body>` tags. I know that it has to be something simple that I am missing but I have seriously looked at this for 4 hours and cannot figure it out. Any help would be kindly appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Audit Activity Report</title>
</head>
<body>
<h4>Audit Activity Report</h4>

<?php
 if (!$_REQUEST['Submit']) { 
   html_form(); 
} else
{ 
 select_cd();  
 }
?>
function html_form()
{

<p>Please enter the fields you would like to run a report on:</p>

<form name="Audit Activity Report" method="post" action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<p>
Employee BEMS: <input name="EmployeeBEMS" type="text" size="10" maxlength="10"> </p>
<p>Escort BEMS:
<input name="EscortBEMS" type="text" size="10" maxlength="10">
</p>
<p>Current Activity ID:
<input name="CurrentActivityID" type="text" size="20" maxlength="20">
</p>
<p>
<label for="LaborTraining">LaborTraining:</label>
<select name="LaborTraining2" id="LaborTraining">
<option>Yes</option>
<option>No</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>
<label for="EthicsTraining">Ethics Training:</label>
<select name="EthicsTraining" id="EthicsTraining">
<option>Yes</option>
<option>No</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>
<label for="WorkAuthorization">Work Authorization:</label>
<select name="WorkAuthorization" id="WorkAuthorization">
<option>Yes</option>
<option>No</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>
<label for="Predicted Outcome">Predicted Outcome:</label>
<select name="Predicted Outcome" id="PredictedOutcome">
<option>Yes</option>
<option>No</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="View Report" /> </p>
<p>
<input type="reset" name="Clear" id="Clear" value="Clear" /> </p>
</form>

}
function select_cd()
{

<h4>Report</h4>


/* set's the variables for MySQL connection */

$server = "******"; // this is the server address and port
$username = "*******"; // change this to your username
$password = "*****"; // change this to your password

/* Connects to the MySQL server */

$link = mysql_connect ($server, $username, $password)
or die (mysql_error());

/* Defines the Active Database for the Connection */

if (!mysql_select_db("a32****_Audit", $link))
{
echo "<p>There has been an error. This is the error message:</p>";
echo "<p><strong>" . mysql_error() . "</strong></p>";
echo "Please Contact Your Systems Administrator with details";
}

/* Sets the SQL Query */

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Audit_Activity_Log";
$sql .= " WHERE ( Audit_Activity_Log.Employee_BEMS_ID =
'{$_POST['EmployeeBEMS']}')";

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM Audit_Activity_Log";
$sql2 .= " WHERE ( Audit_Activity_Log.Escort_BEMS_ID =
'{$_POST['EscortBEMS']}')";

$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM Audit_Activity_Log";
$sql3 .= " WHERE ( Audit_Activity_Log.Current_Activity_ID = '{$_POST['CurrentActivityID']}')";

$sql4 = "SELECT * FROM Audit_Activity_Log";
$sql4 .= " WHERE ( Audit_Activity_Log.Labor_Training= '{$_POST['LaborTraining']}')";

$sql4 = "SELECT * FROM Audit_Activity_Log";
$sql4 .= " WHERE ( Audit_Activity_Log.Ethics_Training= '{$_POST['EthicsTraining']}')";

$sql5 = "SELECT * FROM Audit_Activity_Log";
$sql5 .= " WHERE ( Audit_Activity_Log.Work_Authorization= '{$_POST['WorkAuthorization']}')";

$sql5 = "SELECT * FROM Audit_Activity_Log";
$sql5 .= " WHERE ( Audit_Activity_Log.Predicted_Outcome= '{$_POST['PredictedOutcome']}')";

/* Passes a Query to the Active Database */

$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

if (!$result)
{
echo("<p>Error performing query: " . mysql_error() . "</p>");
exit();
}
/* Passes a Query to the Active Database */
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2, $link);

if (!$result2)
{
echo("<p>Error performing query: " . mysql_error() . "</p>");
exit();
}
/* Passes a Query to the Active Database */
$result3 = mysql_query($sql3, $link);

if (!$result3)
{
echo("<p>Error performing query: " . mysql_error() . "</p>");
exit();
}
/* Passes a Query to the Active Database */

$result4 = mysql_query($sql4, $link);

if (!$result4)
{
echo("<p>Error performing query: " . mysql_error() . "</p>");
exit();
}
/* Passes a Query to the Active Database */
$result5 = mysql_query($sql5, $link);

if (!$result5)
{
echo("<p>Error performing query: " . mysql_error() . "</p>");
exit();
}
/* Starts the table and creates headings */
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Employee BEMS</th>
<th> Escort BEMS</th>
<th> Current Activity ID</th>
<th> Labor Training</th>
<th>Ethics Training</th>
<th>Work Authorization</th>
<th>Predicted Outcome</th>
</tr>";

/* Retrieves the rows from the query result set
and puts them into a HTML table row */

if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo("<tr>\n<td>" . $row["Employee_BEMS_ID"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Escort_BEMS_ID"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Current_Activity_ID"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Labor_Training"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Ethics_Training"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Work_Authorization"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Predicted_Outcome"] . "</td>\n</tr>\n\n");
}
elseif ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo("<tr>\n<td>" . $row["Employee_BEMS_ID"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Escort_BEMS_ID"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Current_Activity_ID"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Labor_Training"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Ethics_Training"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Work_Authorization"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Predicted_Outcome"] . "</td>\n</tr>\n\n");
}
elseif ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result3, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo("<tr>\n<td>" . $row["Employee_BEMS_ID"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Escort_BEMS_ID"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Current_Activity_ID"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Labor_Training"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Ethics_Training"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Work_Authorization"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Predicted_Outcome"] . "</td>\n</tr>\n\n");
}
elseif ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result4, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo("<tr>\n<td>" . $row["Employee_BEMS_ID"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Escort_BEMS_ID"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Current_Activity_ID"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Labor_Training"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Ethics_Training"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Work_Authorization"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Predicted_Outcome"] . "</td>\n</tr>\n\n");
}
elseif ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result5, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
echo("<tr>\n<td>" . $row["Employee_BEMS_ID"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Escort_BEMS_ID"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Current_Activity_ID"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Labor_Training"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Ethics_Training"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Work_Authorization"] . "</td>");
echo("<td>" . $row["Predicted_Outcome"] . "</td>\n</tr>\n\n");
}

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"syntax error on the last line of code(**ish**)"* do I laugh or cry

Answer (score 0):

Your php starting and closing tags are missing -

```
function html_form()
{
```

Do it --

```
<?php

function html_form()
{
```

`HTML` is not recognizing these `php` methods, do it like the way you did earlier in your code.

You need to separate logic part with the view, do it something like the way mentioned below(numerous other ways too for doing it)

```
<?php

//PHP code chunks

?>
HTML Part
<?php

//Another PHP code chunks

?>
Again your HTML part
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that all your PHP code is inside PHP tags.  You can close the PHP tags to write raw HTML.  Here's an example, from your code:

```
<?php
 if (!$_REQUEST['Submit']) { 
   html_form(); 
} else
{ 
 select_cd();  
 }
?>
function html_form()
{
```

You need to change it, because `function html_form() {` is PHP, but it's outside the php tags.  Try it like this:

```
<?php
 if (!$_REQUEST['Submit']) { 
   html_form(); 
} else
{ 
 select_cd();  
 }

function html_form()
{
?>
```

Check over all your code, make sure any PHP code is inside `<?php ?>` tags.

For future reference, when you have PHP errors, be sure to tell us what the error message says and figure out exactly where the error is happening.  It's important.

The error you're describing at the end of the file is because your last set of PHP tags isn't closed.  Check over your code as I have explained and you'll fix the error.  Also look at your output page once the error message is fixed.  If you see anything in your browser that looks like PHP, you missed some PHP open/close tags.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers.  You are missing your Opening and closing PHP tags.

```
<?php ?>
```

Another good way to debug is your Apache error_log, if you use Apache.  Has helped me out a few times.